# Draw a piecewise constant graph from csv

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, csv

I have the following csv file:

```
1,36
2,22
3,13
4,8
5,7
6,2
7,1
8,7
9,12
10,5
11,6
12,2
13,7
14,4
15,4
16,1
17,2
18,1
19,1
20,2
21,2
22,1
23,1
24,1
25,1
26,1
27,2
28,0
29,0
30,0
31,0
32,1
33,0
34,0
35,0
36,1
```

whose name is `file`.

The following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[black,ylabel=Frequency, legend pos=outer north east]
  \addplot table[col sep=comma] {file.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces the plot:
[image]

It's fine but I would like to draw instead a piecewise constant graph. E.g. if we look at `file`, we have

```
1,36
```

corresponds to a constant line between 1 and 2, with constant ordinate 36,

```
2,22
```

corresponds to a constant line between 2 and 3, with constant ordinate 22 and so on.

Comment: Does `const plot` help? `\addplot[const plot,...]`

Comment: @user187803 Yes! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I extend my comment to a full answer here.)

You can use the `const plot` option for `\addplot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents*}{file.csv}
1,36
2,22
3,13
4,8
5,7
6,2
7,1
8,7
9,12
10,5
11,6
12,2
13,7
14,4
15,4
16,1
17,2
18,1
19,1
20,2
21,2
22,1
23,1
24,1
25,1
26,1
27,2
28,0
29,0
30,0
31,0
32,1
33,0
34,0
35,0
36,1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=Frequency]
  \addplot+[const plot] table[col sep=comma] {file.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```